# How to add an image generating API in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I make a function to generate images using an Api but i am not able to use or i am not able pick the API.

```kotlin
 private fun generateMeme() {
        val url = ""

        val memeTypes = listOf("afraid", "blb", "cb", "gak", "keanu", "mordor", "puffin", "sad-clinton", "sad-obama", "saltbae", "thinking-ape")
        val memeType = memeTypes.random()
        val requestUrl = "${url}${memeType}/${memeText.text.toString()}.jpg"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val imageRequest = ImageRequest(requestUrl, { response ->
            memeImage.setImageBitmap(response)
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, { error ->
            Log.e("MemeGenerator", "Error fetching meme image: ${error.message}")
        })

        queue.add(imageRequest)
    }
```

I made this function to generate Api and i used some API but i am not able to extract images and the screen remains black.

Comment: No errors? What does the debugger say? You need to be more precise with your question. Please elaborate exactly what is not working and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried to add API but I am not able to extract the images or memes, can you help with that task?

Comment: It's difficult to help you because you're not explaining the problem. Are you getting an error from the API? Are you getting a runtime error? Like I said, you need to explain _exactly_ what the problem is that you are facing and not just state what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).